# Finding the contents of an Array 'a' after the loop completes

Tags: arrays

Im a beginner and i really need help understand this.
so i have this array;

```
int [ ]a = {1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,0}; 
for (int i = 1 ; i < 10; i++) {a[ i ] = a[ i - 1];}
```

my assumption is that the content would now be (1.2.3.4.5.4.3.2.1) deleting the zero. am i wrong, if so how, and what is the right answer?

Comment: Did you tried running it ? Your expectations are wrong.

Comment: You are not resizing the array. Just reassigning some of the values. Why ask us? Why not just try it and see?

Comment: It gives me [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
but i have reasons to believe I'm doing something wrong.
that uncertainty comes from little experience with methods and Arrays and what they have to do with each other

Comment: No, that's correct. If you don't get why, add some print statements to see the value of `a[i]` and `a[i-1]`. Or use a debugger to step through it.